# In Kohana 3, can I conditionally validate fields, only if they're set in $_POST?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Normally, you can use code such as this to validate incoming data:

```
$post = Validate::factory($_POST);
$post->rules('field_name', array(
    'not_empty' => null, // Must be non-empty.
    'regex' => '/\d+/' // Must be a digit. 
));
```

[ Yes, I know to move field validation rules to a Model ]

In this particular case, I'd like to only validate certain fields only if they were actually present in the $_POST data.

Is this accomplished by simply leaving out the `not_empty` rule, or will the `regex` rule (in this case) still not be satisfied, and fail validation? (my assumption).

This looks like it might solve the issue (haven't tried yet) but I wonder if this is the best practice in this case, or if this would be "the right way"...

```
$post->rules( /*... some rules I always want... */ ); 
if (isset($_POST['field_name'])) {
    $post->rules( /* ... conditionally applied rules ... */ ); 
}
```

What's the Kohana way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not_empty will only make sure the value isn't empty (empty array, null, false, '' - more like !empty() as a function, not as a lang. construct).

You can do it this way manually (as you proposed), although a callback seems like a more valid solution in your case (which would check for your conditions, does it really have to be $_POST, maybe you want to check those keys / conditions for other arrays as well?).

Comment: In this case, I'm wanting to update a model that's already saved to the database. I of course need the ID to retrieve the original record. Aside from that, if I'm only passed an ID and a "description", I don't need to validate other fields that already exist, as I have done so during the Create process. Does that make sense? Do you mean that a single callback function, perhaps on the model, that validates information if present/not? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the single callback method would do it :)